# Does Chrome actually preload HSTS?

Tags: google-chrome, hsts

I'm using Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 under Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. If I clear my cache, it looks like no domains stay in the HSTS set, although [some should be preloaded](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json). I'm using what I consider safe, old domains, such as mail.google.com, but under "Query Domain" of chrome://net-internals/#hsts I get "Not found" until I actually visit mail.google.com for the first time.

This seems to beat the point of [preloading your site](https://hstspreload.appspot.com/). Any thoughts?

Comment: Chrome 32...? That is over 10 versions (over a year) behind the stable version. Many security bugs have been uncovered and fixed in this timespan. If you still browse with such an old version of Chrome, don't get surprised when your system gets compromised. I strongly suggest to update to the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Rob. I thought maybe that was "current" for Ubuntu =S... I had to run `sudo apt-get -f install` and install the package again. Now I'm running 42.0.2311.90 and it does show mail.google.com et al in the HSTS set. Time to reset passwords, I guess! Thanks again!